# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)

Tags: spring, log4j, version, upgrade, stack-overflow

I am working on a spring multi module project. I have upgraded spring version from 3.x to 5.3.17.  After upgradation, while running project Iam getting following error:
Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.StackOverflowError`
`at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)`
`at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jAdapter.createLocationAwareLog(LogAdapter.java:130)`
`at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:91)`
`at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)`
`at org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerFactory.getLogger(JCLLoggerFactory.java:88)`
`at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)`
`at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jAdapter.createLocationAwareLog(LogAdapter.java:130)`
`at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:91)`
`at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)`
`at org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerFactory.getLogger(JCLLoggerFactory.java:88)`

in build.gradle file:
compile(group: "org.springframework", name: "spring-core", version: "3.0.5.RELEASE").Here version changed to 5.3.17
similar things applied for spring-context,spring-web etc spring related dependencies in build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

Your SLF4J uses JCL as backend and your JCL uses SLF4J as backend, hence the StackOverflow.

Newer versions of Spring have [`spring-jcl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jcl) as transitive dependency and they redirect logging coded using Jakarta Commons Logging to SLF4J.

If moreover you have a [`slf4j-jcl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jcl) binding on your classpath that performs the opposite redirect, you get a `StackOverflowException`.

Just remove `slf4j-jcl` from your dependencies and you should be fine.